# How can I guarantee a Dialog will be re-formed after canceled?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog that pops up some information on a list, when a long click is performed. The information depends on which list entry the click is performed on. However, I'm noticing that when I view the information, and close it (Via calling it with a dialog.cancel() command), that the next time I open the dialog, it doesn't bother to get the information again, it just pops up the same dialog that I saw before. Any tips for overcoming this problem? Thanks!

Some further information. The dialog is generated using a showDialog(int) command. From there, it is called through an onCreateDialog(int) command in a master activity.

EDIT: I managed to get this to work by using the removeDialog(int) command in the onClickListener of the Dialog (It just removes itself when it dies). I can't for the life of me find a more elegant solution, but I'd much prefer one. Thanks guys!

Edit: NM, realized the answer was already posted here... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use more info, but are you using [`onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog%29) or [`onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareDialog%28int,%20android.app.Dialog,%20android.os.Bundle%29)?

You should let the activity handle the creation and showing of Dialogs. onPrepareDialog will ensure the dialog has the correct info before it is displayed to the user.

Comment: I'm not using either of the opPrepareDialog() commands. Should I?

Answer (score 0):

You need to rerun the routine that populated the dialog in the first place.

Comment: I'm using the showDialog(int) command to show the dialog. However, so far as I can tell, it is just using the version already stored in memory...